# Application not able to access newly added table in sybase.

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sybase

We have added a new table in sybase DB. Trying to access that table through application but end up getting "NO table exist table" error.

In Sybase it is available .

Connection also reestablished through application but end up getting same above error.

Comment: Did you `commit` the `create table`?

Comment: "access through application" ... you mean the one you don't give details about? If an exception is thrown then it has a stack trace. The JPA provider has a LOG which is for you to look at. This is a process called "debugging"

Comment: Are we talking about Sybase ASE, Sybase IQ or Sybase SQL Anywhere?

Regardless, what is the owner of the table? And what is the user in the session trying to access it? If they are different, you will need to specify the table owner when acessing it.